# Size Tab Missing In Adjust Computer Size And Position NVIDIA Control Panel

Tags: nvidia-settings

I have a gt710 2gb, and I want to resize the screen as my sharp tv overscan my computer. I tried to underscan it, but my mom is getting angry to me because every time she will open the computer, she needs to underscan it.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Have you tried bypassing the NVIDIA control panel and adjust it through Windows (2nd monitor)?

Comment: Hello I already fix it by replacing my HDMI cable and it works thanks